# Problem starting virtualbox after installing docker

Tags: docker, windows-10, virtualbox

I installed Docker on my windows 10 home, Docker works fine, but VirtualBox stopped working, and I can no longer run my virtual machines.

I have looked for information, but I have not found a solution (perhaps it is because the compatibility of docker for windows 10 home recently appeared).

Is there a possibility of having both tools installed and running correctly? and how could I do it?

Virtualbox shows me the following error (This started to happen to me after the docker installation).

> VMMR0_DO_NEM_INIT_VM failed: VERR_NEM_MISSING_KERNEL_API_2 (VERR_NEM_MISSING_KERNEL_API_2).
> VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX).
> Código resultado: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
> Componente: ConsoleWrap
> Interfaz: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}